# Add Pop Up / Welcome Box to WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a pop box that automatically appears on the home page for everyone containing text or an image or anything, my script is WordPress

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins like Popup box
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ays-popup-box/

Or You need any custom popup then use like bootstrap popup.